# How do I stop some form of text wrapping happening between divs?

Tags: html, css

[image]

When I change the font and the size I get some weird wrapping as shown in the picture below. Not sure how to stop this and why its happening?

I've pasted the HTML and CSS code below thats being used.It looks like the text maybe wrapping?

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="block1">
    <p><img src="img/cheese1.jpg" alt="Cheese Picture" id="intro_pic" ></p>
    <h2 id="intro">
        The best selection of cheese I've ever seen! Cannot wait for our  next order!
    </h2>
</div>

</div>

    <div class="wrap">
    <div id="block2">
    <h2 id="intro2">
        The best selection of cheese I've ever seen! Cannot wait for our  next order!
    </h2>
    <p><img src="img/cheese1.jpg" alt="Cheese Picture" id="intro_pic2" ></p>
        </div>


    .wrap {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 58%;
-webkit-columns: 100px 2;
    box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 50px auto;
padding: 40px;
width: 78%;
border: 1px solid rgba(87,104,115, .9);
border-radius: 12px;
background: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
    }

    #intro {
padding: 1.3em 0 1.3em 0;
text-align: left;
float: right;
font-size: 3em;
line-height: 1.5;
letter-spacing: -1px; 
color: #2B9BD4;
margin: 1.35em 0 .8em 0;
 overflow: hidden;
    }

    #intro2 {
padding: 1.3em 0 1.3em 0;
text-align: right;
float: right;
font-size: 3em;
line-height: 1.5;
letter-spacing: -1px; 
color: #2B9BD4;
margin: 1.35em 0 .8em 0;
 overflow: hidden;
    }

    #intro_pic {
text-align: left;
float: right;
    }

    #intro_pic2 {
text-align: right;
float: left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined -webkit-columns on your .wrap div, so it forces the content to assume a column layout and wraps your heading like that.

If you are using the floating method (which is a lot more flexible in terms of browser compatibility), you have no need for the column structure.

Your issue is located here:

```
.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 58%;
  -webkit-columns: 100px 2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 78%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(87,104,115, .9);
  border-radius: 12px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually trying to experiment with the column layout. I'm aware that its not fully supported, just seems interesting to use this instead of grids etc. So there is no way around it without removing colums? Just a quick other question. How do I reduce the gap between the block 1 and 2 divs? Thanks alot.

Comment: Using a column layout will force your elements on a column style flow,  that is why the wrap an leave parts of the text on one column and other on the other side, since it is flowing the image and the heading through the columns. The 'block' divs are not direct to one another, since they are both childs of the .wrap divs. So you should change the .wrap div margin's vertical values in order to alter the gap between both divs ;)

Comment: Sorry last question! to reduce the gaps in the #block 1 and #block2 I'd need to create a css rule for this, is this vertical values as well?

Comment: The 'block' divs are not direct siblings to one another, since they are both childs of different .wrap divs. So you should change the .wrap div margin's vertical values in order to alter the gap between both divs ;)